# Add cokies using Java before page load

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cookies, automation

Is that possible to add cookies using Java before the page load? Or the only way is to go to the site first and only then the cookies can be added?

I'm logging to the Site1 in session1 and have cookies saved. Then I start a new session2 in a different browser and want to have cookies added before I visit Site1 in order to avoid logging again (the site is designed in the way I will always get login screen if I have no active session). But I'm not sure how to add them since there is no site specified in the Cookies storage yet (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TODvI.png)

I know there is driver.manage().addCookie() method which can be used, but this is working correctly only if we have the site opened, otherwise I'm getting InvalidCookieDomainException. In my case I'm trying to achieve the situation when I add cookies first and then visit the site - this way I should not get the login screen since I have cookies added.

I was unable to find the solution on the internet, trying to understand if that's possible at all.

Comment: In Java, using Selenium WebDriver, it is not possible to add cookies to a website before the page loads. The reason is that the cookies are associated with a specific domain, and the WebDriver needs to have a session with that domain in order to add cookies successfully.
When you create a new WebDriver session, it starts with an incognito mode with nothing associated, meaning it has no cookies or session information. You need to navigate to the website first before you can add cookies to that domain.